# Convergence of series questions!

Tags: analysis

Here are a couple of more problems on series convergence:

1) Is there a real number c such that the following series converges? Prove your answer: $\sum (e - (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n + \frac{c}{n})$, where the series goes from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$

I tried using ratio test, but that turned out really messy and then I tried the fact that $lim (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ goes to e as $n\to \infty$ and then we are left with $c\sum \frac{1}{n}$ which diverges unless $c=0$, but I am not sure if it is true that $\lim (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ and $\sum (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ are the same things.

2) Does the series $\frac21 -\frac72 +\frac53 +\frac24 -\frac75 +\frac56 +\frac27 -\frac78 +\frac59 +\ldots$ converge? Legal definition of the series: $∑ \frac{a_n}{n}$ as n goes from 1 to infinity, where $a_n = 2$ if  $n-3(\frac{n}{3}) = 1$, $a_n = -7$ if $n- 3(\frac{n}{3}) = 2$,  $a_n = 5$ if  $n -3(n/3) = 0$, i.e., if $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Quite honestly I didn't even understand this last problem. Please share your insights and answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have usion taylor series

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)=\exp\left(n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\right)\\=\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$
so with the choice
$$c=-\frac{e}{2}$$
the given series is convergent by comparison with the series $\displaystyle\sum_n\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: So you used the taylor series expansion of log? Also how did you get c=-e/2? Can you please explain the intermediate steps?

Comment: We choose this value of $c$ to cancel the term $\frac{e}{2n}$ in the expansion of $\log$ which gives a divergent series.

Comment: In the 2nd line of equations, shouldn't it be e^(1- 1/2n + ...)? I still can't understand how you would get e/2n if -1/2n is in the power of the exponential term?

Comment: In the second line
$$\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\=e\exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$
using the Taylor expansion of the $\exp$ function.

Comment: oh ok. Looks great. thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on the 2nd question?